# Define window and use it in several analytic columns

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions, data-partitioning

I have an oracle query in which I need use several analytic functions within the same window. How can I define a window once and then use it for each of these calls?

I.e. I wanna to write it like in PostGRESql:

```sql
SELECT
    sum(salary) OVER w,
    avg(salary) OVER w
FROM empsalary
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY depname ORDER BY salary DESC);
```

Forgot to mention, the goal is to avoid code duplication, not to speed up the query.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle does not support that syntax. Just specify the window in each analytic statement:

```
SELECT
    sum(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY depname ORDER BY salary DESC),
    avg(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY depname ORDER BY salary DESC)
FROM empsalary;
```

If you look at the explain plan for the query then there should only be a single `WINDOW (SORT)` operation as Oracle knows to re-use the window for both statements.

Comment: Sad. The goal was to avoid code duplication, not to speed up the query.

Comment: Feel free to suggest your amendment to Oracle: https://community.oracle.com/community/database/database-ideas

Answer (score 0):

Starting from version 20c Oracle supports window clause syntax.

> [Enhanced Analytic Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/newft/enhanced-analytic-functions.html)
>
> **The query_block clause of a SELECT statement now supports the window_clause, which implements the window clause of the SQL standard table expression as defined in the SQL:2011 standard.**
>
> [SELECT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/sqlrf/SELECT.html)

So your query will work perfectly fine without changes:

```
SELECT
    sum(salary) OVER w,
    avg(salary) OVER w
FROM empsalary
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY depname ORDER BY salary DESC);
```